# How do I interpret the random effect in my mixed-effects model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, interpretation

I have run a linear mixed effects model with `individual` as a random effect. I have three separate measurements of each individual. The random effect is significant, and explains more of the variance than the fixed effects in the model.

Do I interpret this as due to low within individual variation, or high within individual variation?

Answer (score 1):

You would interpret this as there being high within-individual variation *relative* to the variation explainable by your fixed effects. It's difficult to judge whether the absolute level is low or high without knowing a great deal more about your problem, your field, and your data.